# How to execute the `case` in the `select` statement only if some conditions are satisfied

Tags: go, concurrency

I have a channel:

```
aChan := make(chan struct{})
```

and a timeout duration `var t time.Duration`. I want the program to exit either if the channel is closed, or the `t` timeout is reached,
**if t is a positive duration**.

I know I can use an outer if else loop, but this looks very redundant:

```
    if t >= time.Duration(0) {
        select {
        case <-time.After(t):
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stdout, "timeout!"))
            close(timeoutChan)
        case <-aChan:
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stdout, "aChan is closed"))
            return
        }
    } else {
        select {
        case <-aChan:
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stdout, "aChan is closed"))
            return
        }
    }
```

Is there a more elegant way to write this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `nil` channel for the timeout when the  duration is less than zero.  The timeout case with a `nil` channel is not executed because receive on a `nil` channel is never ready.

```
var after <-chan time.Time
if t >= 0 {
    after = time.After(t)
}
select {
case <-after:
    fmt.Println("timeout!")
    close(timeoutChan)
case <-aChan:
    fmt.Println("aChan is closed")
    return
}
```